KEEP = false function in Simple Table Server in Jmeter
Can anyone explain me the function KEEP=FALSE in Simple Table Server.
Will the data be deleted even if the login fails or will it be retried till the login happens.
I'm new to this STS in Jmeter. A detailed description for the above function will be helpful.
I tried the KEEP=FALSE functionality but not sure if the login failed data is deleted or being reused to login.

Have you tried to read the documentation?


KEEP=TRUE => the data is kept and put to the end of list
KEEP=FALSE => the data is removed


The data is not deleted from the source CSV file, but it's removed from in-memory storage. HTTP Simple Table Server knows nothing about the status of your request and doesn't care whether it was successful or not.
If you have doubts you can always take a look into the source code
In case you need better control over test data including capability to add/remove/amend entries on the fly - take a look at Redis Data Set Plugin
